# can mpi reduce be used for string array in java?

Tags: java, mpi

I'm doing my class assignment about word counting from an input file. All of my classmate using the `mpi_send` and `mpi_recv` for this assignment.

While i'm still wondering if `mpi_reduce` really cannot be used in this particular task since we have try it but can't find the exact solution. This code is using the hashmap and arraylist. Below is the code:

```
    //split each line into word-by-word and count the occurrences
    for(int i=0; i < inline.size(); i++) 
    {           
        //to read line by line
        String input = inline.get(i);

        //to split the string on whitespace using regular expression "\\s+"
        String[] words = input.split("\\s+");

    for(int j =0;j<words.length;j++) {
            //start counting the occurences
            for (String word : words) 
            {
                 wordMap.put(word,
                   (wordMap.get(word) == null ? 1 : (wordMap.get(word) + 1)));
            }
            localSum[0]+= words[j];
        }

    }
    int [] globalSum = new int [1];

    //using reduce method
    MPI.COMM_WORLD.Reduce(localSum, 0, globalSum, 0, localSum.length, MPI.OBJECT, MPI.PROD, 0);

    //for time taken
    toc=MPI.Wtime();

    //to ensure all process are completed so that it can proceed to next step
    MPI.COMM_WORLD.Barrier();

    //to display the result at rank 0
    if (rank == 0)
    {
        //display the result
        System.out.println("The results :");
        for (String name: wordMap.keySet()){
            String key =name.toString();
            String value = wordMap.get(name).toString();  
            System.out.println("I am process "+ rank +" "+ key + " = " + value);  
        }
        //display the time
        System.out.println("The time takens :"+ (toc-tic)/100);
```

Comment: @cricket_007 i've already insert my code. Hope u can view it. thanx in adv

Comment: what do you want to reduce ? an `int[]` ? an `int` ?, a string (?)
also, please trim your code and only keep the part relevant to the communication.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet string [] actually.

Comment: please update (and trim !) your code accordingly then.

Comment: out of curiosity, what result do you expect from a reduction on `string[]` ?

Comment: as written, your code (incorrectly) reduces `int[]`, not `string` or `string[]`